# Can't load all comments on a website because they're loading while scrolling (through a java web client)

Tags: java, web-scraping

I'm working on a java web scraper that someone else has written in a terrible way. It is very difficult to understand anything, and there is no comment at all. It is supposed to retrieve articles and their comments on different press websites.

My problem is that one of these website displays only 10 comments, and load more comments only if you scroll down. The point is that I need ALL the comments, not only the first ten, but I don't know how my web client could immitate a scroll down, or if there is any other and better way.

After some research, I've found that configuring a very high `InnerHeight` might resolve the problem, but I have no idea about how it works, and I don't even know if it can resolve my problem...

The website I am trying to scrape is :

https://www.lefigaro.fr/international/le-climat-se-tend-en-allemagne-face-aux-restrictions-anti-corona-20201025

To load the comments, you have to click on the blue button at the end of the page "LIRE LES  COMMENTAIRES"

Can someone help ?

Thanks :)  !

Comment: the scrolling will issue more http requests, perhaps the whole list loads with an ajax call, probably returning json. just find out the request and get thedata (probably json) directly. Otherwise you could use selenium to issue scroll down clicks. I'd scrap the old scraper and use some proper tools, there are scraping frameworks out there.

Comment: @curiosa ok I'll check that ! ty :)

Comment: You just "said my phrase."  I used to try to scrape the **Yahoo! News Comments** - unfortunately, I resorted to clicking by hand and then saving them to a file for **Reg Ex** Processing.  Recently I discovered another feature of **Chrome Developer Tools** which helps search for specific **AJAX Calls** in mountains of `Java-Script` that many pages include / use.  If you post the `URL` of the site you are trying to scrape, and update your question, perhaps somebody would be able to locate the **Java Script** on the page - _and call / invoke the call_.  That's your best bet.

Comment: Some of the news sites (like **Yahoo! News**) have started disallowing comment threads on their news sources...

Comment: @Y2020-09 thanks for your comments. I've just updated my post and to include the website I'm trying to scrap. After some research, I've discoverd that I can acces to comments in JSON format by using a URL that  I can guess from the article html. I will also check AJAX.

Comment: I (try) to read Spanish (and Mandarin / 普通话)...  I would love to read French - but I don't.  The three comments on the page are inside an HTML `<DIV>` and also a `<SCRIPT TYPE='json'>` as well.  To get all 28 of them you will have to follow along **Chrome Dev Tools** to pick out the appropriate **Java Script** invokation.  I am producing a movie right now, and I could try, but languages I don't read are more difficult for me.

Comment: **Selenium** (as you said) probably / possibly would also work... But it is more complicated.  I have asked how to run (headless) **Google Chrome** in `Google Cloud Platform`, but have never received a proper answer on **Stack Overflow** (yet, but I guess I will ask again soon).